# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Code Review's [first moderator election](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 4 new moderators are:

[image: Simon André Forsberg] [image: 200_success] [image: Jamal] [image: Mat's Mug]

Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! (Or at least the two who were not *pro tempore* moderators. ;-)

Please also thank the outgoing moderator, [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl), who did so much to make this site successful.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4947582459576320/0).

Comment: Yes, advice, please! I have no idea how a Mug and I can fill the shoes of a monkey.

Answer (score 37):

Congratulations to the four of you, and all the best.

A dream team for sure, and, if you need some advice, well, don't call me, I will be on holiday ;-)

Comment: tempted to -1 for not providing advice ;-)

Comment: [Congrats, you called it.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=22762591#22762591) :-D

Answer (score 25):

Thanks, rolfl, for your enormous contribution to the community.  Without your effort, we would not be where we are today.  I'll miss having your wisdom on the moderation team and your watchful eye on the events in the rest of Stack Exchange.

Congratulations to Simon, Mat's Mug, and Jamal!  I believe the community has chosen wisely, and I look forward to working with you.

Thanks to everyone who voted and all the candidates who ran: you've all done your part to make Code Review's election the biggest graduation election in Stack Exchange history.  I'm glad to see that everyone ran a clean campaign.  =)

Comment: *Phew*.  I thought I was gonna get caught stuffing the ballot box.  Oops...

Answer (score 22):

Congratuations to the new moderators!  Thanks to all of the candidates (and voters) for your participation, and sincere thanks to the outgoing moderators for keeping the ship afloat until now.  There were so many excellent candidates that it's clear that Code Review will be a vital resource for a long time.

Answer (score 14):

I find it awesome that we were able to keep two great moderators AND add two of our most dynamic users to the team.

Simon and Mat's Mug, you guys will certainly get the best mentoring possible from the old timers and together I'm sure you'll raise the bar even further for this site!

Congratulations to all and big thanks to rolfl for all the contribution. Enjoy the well earned rest ;)

Answer (score 7):

Sad to see *[rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503)* going, glad to see *[Simon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562)* and *[Mat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788)* added to the team. Well done guys, I sincerely think you are the right guys for the position. Now I'm only wondering which principle was applied here: Dilbert's or Peter's?