# It looks like it's finally time

Tags: discussion, moderators

Well, somehow I didn't see this coming for a while, but it looks like it's the best time to move on after all these years.

I've been here since 2013, which I believe was two years after CR was founded.  Not long after that, I noticed that [a previous mod](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/winston-ewert-is-no-longer-a-moderator) was gone, and then I eventually took his place.  After receiving my diamond, I noticed that the other two mods at the time were inactive, so I tried to find out what was going on.  It was later on from there when [our first election](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5720/2015-community-moderator-election-results) was finished and I was the only winning incumbent.

We all took CR in a new direction, especially after graduation.  Lots of cleanup of old posts was done, unanswered question attention addressed, and tags feeling the burnination.  Some of us went on over time and new mods took our place, taking on newer challenges.  I was fortunate to oversee much of this, and while I couldn't tell what I would be doing years in the future, I obviously didn't foresee COVID and the many changes that it brought.

While my circumstances aren't directly COVID-related, they did indirectly bring some changes for me, as it did for many others.  Other things in life have changed as well and I just don't have the same drive as I did almost a decade ago.  But then, most don't make it that far and that's okay.  It's hard to move on after so many years, regardless of what it is, but it has to be done.

I would like to extend my thanks to [Monkey](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl), [200_success](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), [Simon](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg), [Vogel](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37660/vogel612), [Mug](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mathieu-guindon), [Janos](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos), [Malachi](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18427/malachi), and the late [Phrancis](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42632/phrancis).  We have done much together and they are indeed great people to work with.  I couldn't do it all without them, especially when I was pretty much alone at the start.  I would also like to apologize to the current mods who probably needed more guidance but when I wasn't around as much.  A number of things have hit me, mostly health-related ones that I've never experienced, and I just lost sight of things for a while (and I somehow forgot that I could've marked myself as inactive all this time).  I honestly didn't think I would slack off like that, but then that's another life lesson for me: don't beat yourself up for things like this, especially things you can't quite control.  If anything, I'm glad I didn't forget things entirely and to the point of falling off the radar without an actual farewell.

So with that, I'm handing in my diamond and allowing a slot for a new mod who may take my place, or at least to not have another inactive mod hang around.  But in the future if things settle down and IF it seems right, I may run in a future election.  Once again, I can't obsess too much about the future, but I have to do what I feel is right.

Comment: I trust you'll continue to pop in from time to time as an ordinary member?

Comment: @TobySpeight: Absolutely, especially once I get more of my stuff together.  I still need to think more on my career, but some small positive changes with that have happened recently.  Cybersecurity has been more on my mind in recent years...

Comment: Take care and stay well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the torch!

Comment: Wow, you will be missed! Feels weird to +1 this type of post :/

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for your years of service, Jamal!  You have guided the site through what I think of as its adolescent years, and it's matured into a reasonably well-adjusted adult; your contribution has been pivotal to that.

Answer (score 17):

While it is unfortunate for us to have this happen we wish you the best with future endeavors. The site would not be what it is without all of your contributions. I've looked up to you as master <strike>editor</strike> [Jamalizer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/120114) and while I may never edit as many posts or as quickly I will do what I can to continue the legacy.

We look forward to having you participate in the future when you are able to do so.

Comment: To be honest, it might've been quite a strong drive to keep the site clean, plus OCD.  But after a while, I realized that trying to edit all posts needing some editing is pointless, especially for one person, given the volume of posts.  But I'm glad I at least cleaned up some of the older stuff and set an example in the process. :)

Comment: @Mast pointed out yesterday in the 2nd Monitor that I can still be Jamalized.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for all you've done for the community, you've made a difference!

I'm sad to see you go, but do what feels right for you, and don't beat yourself up.

See you around Jamal!